# Home test for the presence of sugar in erythritol

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, food-chemistry

Is there a test to distinguish [erythritol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythritol) from sugar at home without expensive lab equipment or exotic reagents?  Sometimes I purchase erythritol online and wonder if it's been diluted with sugar.

Comment: I would consult with a doctor regarding symptoms. It should be relatively straightforward for a properly equipped lab to test composition but I can't think of a suitable and simple home test. There should be labels on the product - is this from a reputable vendor?

Comment: Clearly I didn't word this clearly.  I'm not asking for medical advice, just a simple chemistry question: how does one test for erythritol vs sugar.  Answering my own question: erythritol melts at 121 C, while sugar (sucrose) melts at 186 C.  I imagine there are other tests, such as solvents that dissolve one but not the other.

Comment: It's a good question, but it remains broad and unclear. It sounds like you want to run a home test. I would say a number of spectroscopic techniques will give you clear cut information, but you are unlikely to have access if you aren't working in a lab. On the other hand there are chemical tests for sugars that  distinguish them from polyols. I'm no expert on this aspect but I suspect this would be a good  start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molisch%27s_test    You can't run just any test for sugars, because sucrose is a so-called nonreducing sugar.

Comment: See also: https://theskepticalchemist.com/demonstration-benedicts-test-reducing-sugars/

Comment: BTW remove any suggestion that this is for personal medical reasons (you can *edit* your post) and the question might be reopened. Hopefully my comments will provide useful pointers.